# Render Component by function Call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sick of defining states to render Components on condition. Most of the time I just need to show some kind of notification or alert. I want to know how can I render a component by calling a function from that Component.

I have found some sample code that is doing exactly what I want, but I can´t reverse engineer it to implement this on my own as I have no clue how the `Modal.info()` function is adding itself to the DOM.

**I want to recreate the `Modal` Component for myself and display it by calling `MyModal.info()`.**

```
import { Modal, Button, Space } from 'antd';

const Item = (props: ItemProps) => {
    const { itemGroup, items } = props;

function info() {
  Modal.info({
    title: 'This is a notification message',
    content: (
      <div>
        <p>some messages...some messages...</p>
        <p>some messages...some messages...</p>
      </div>
    ),
    onOk() {},
  });
}

    return (
        <div className="py-6">
            <div
                onClick={() => info()}
                className="cursor-pointer py-6 px-6 text-3xl font-heading font-bold bg-primary text-white"
            >
                <p>{itemGroup.text}</p>
            </div>
            <div className={`${isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'} duration-200 transition-all p-3 bg-gray-200`}>
                <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6">
                    {items.map((x) => (
                        <ItemCard key={x.id} itemData={x} />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Soory, I tried to answer but maybe I didn't understood you goal. Could you explain better?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I have updated the question. Maybe you can understand it better now, that I want to create that behaviour/component myself.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now I understood.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following solution.

**Notification.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Notifier {
    static warn() {
        if (!document) return;
        const rootElement = document.getElementById('__next');
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Notification), rootElement);
    }
}

const Notification = () => {
    return (
             <div className="w-full h-full bg-red-500 absolute top-0 left-0">Notification Content</div>
           );
};
```

With this solution I can insert anywhere I want my Modal by calling `Notifier.warn()`.

The only thing I am insecure about is the bundle size from `ReactDOM` which actually ads 125Kb to `Notification.tsx`.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to call Modal.info() like this

```
  <Modal.info
    title='This is a notification message',
    content={) => (
      <div>
        <p>some messages...some messages...</p>
        <p>some messages...some messages...</p>
      </div>
    )}
    onOk={() => {}}
  />;
```

All functional components can be called like components.

If this doesn't work then Modal.info is not a component.

To trigger it you should follow the first example from the docs.

https://ant.design/components/modal/

You need to manage some sort of state to tell the Modal to open, functional components can manage something like state using hooks.

Like here
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

For custom, you will need to create your own modal design, likely in a react portal, design as you want. But opening/closing will be handled through useState hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Component = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open</Button>
      {open && <Modal>
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Close</Button>
      </Modal> }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I was asking how can I implement this on my own and not how to use antd.

Comment: Oh, you should have been a little more clear

Just do the same thing except create your Modal component, the `open` bool is used to determine if it should open or not.

Comment: Ok, can you create please a second component called `MyModal` with a function called `info()`. Then remove the state from `Component` and call `MyModal.info()` from the button onClick to display it? As I am reading my question I explained I am sick of defining states to to render Components on condition..

Comment: I don't believe that would work, you can create a custom modal component that handles it's own state, that way it can close itself but you are going to need something that sets some sort of external state so that the modal knows when to open it. The number of times you need to setup the state handlers will depend on how your overall app is designed but at a minimum, open will need to be setup.